# Looking for multiple words js Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, words

I'm trying to write a simple if statement that looks to see if a word matches some other words. I can get this to work when I use just one word but not with multiple words like below. When I use `if (||)`.
I would like to use "contains" but can't see how to use this with a var

Also: ("Woven || Main") is a var so I need this part to stay together.

var option="Woven || Main";

This does not work:

```
var titleIs = "Knit";

if (titleIs.match("Woven || Main")) {

    alert("Main")

}
```

This works:

```
var titleIs = "Knit";

if (titleIs.match("Woven")) {

    alert("Main")

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var words = ['Woven', 'Main'];
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + words.join('|') + ')$');

if (regex.test(titleIs)) {...}
```

Comment: This looks good but how would I make Woven|Main a var? Thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you, I also used this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821875/check-for-multiple-words

Answer (score 1):

```
var titleIs = "Knit";
      if(titleIs.match("Woven") || titleIs.match("Main")){
      alert("Main")
}
```

Comment: ("Woven || Main") is a var so I need this part to stay together.

var option="Woven || Main";

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using || between strings Use the || between match calls.

```
var titleIs = "Knit";
if(titleIs.match("Woven") || titleIs.match("Main")){
   alert("Main")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Array of words and `Array.prototype.indexOf` to check if the Array contains your title.

```
var words = ["Woven", "Main"];
var titleIs = "Knit";

function contains(arr, str) {
    return !!~arr.indexOf(str)
}
console.log(contains(words, titleIs)); //false
```

*Note:*

> Array.prototype.reduce is an ECMAScript 5 addition; as such it may not be present in other implementations of the standard.

*To support older browsers, you can use the [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) MDN provides*

Heres an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ifimab/1/edit)