# Check for multiple words

Tags: javascript, testing, words

I have one problem with this code when I add more than one word to the titleIs Var it does not fire the if statement. The top one does not work ie if a word is in Var titleIs and is in var words, fire the if statement.

Thank you for your help!

```
var titleIs = ['Knit', 'Main'];
var words = ['Woven', 'Main'];
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + words.join('|') + ')$');
if (regex.test(titleIs)) {
alert("true")
}
```

These two work:

```
var titleIs = ['Woven'];
var words = ['Woven', 'Main'];
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + words.join('|') + ')$');
if (regex.test(titleIs)) {
alert("true")
}

var titleIs = ['Main'];
var words = ['Woven', 'Main'];
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + words.join('|') + ')$');
if (regex.test(titleIs)) {
alert("true")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` method accepts a single string. (in fact when you send an array with only one element, it takes that element into account).

You need a new method called `testAny` to be defined like this:

```
RegExp.prototype.testAny = function (arr){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (this.test(arr[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

(in fact `matchesAny` is a better name - in my opinion - but used the above name to keep it consistent with the existing `test` method)

and then be used in your `if` instead.

```
if(regex.testAny(titleIs)) ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I also used this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822339/title-attribute-array

Comment: URW! eventhough `testAny` answer your question as stated here, but I think what you need is to define `Array.prototype.intersects(anotherArray)`. and I'm sure there are faster ways to implement it than using `regEx` (as you are doing here).

Answer (score 0):

RegExp expects a String, not an Array.

So check each word one by one:

```
var titleIs = ['Knit', 'Main'];
var words = ['Woven', 'Main'];
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + words.join('|') + ')$');
for(var i=0; i<titleIs.length; i++){
    if (regex.test(titleIs[i])) {
        alert("true")
    }
}
```

The reason it works with just a single item in the Array is that Javascript is coercing your array into the String `"Knit"`. With two items in the list it is coerced into `"Knit,Main"` and with that comma in the middle no longer matches your regex.

Comment: This alerts several times if more than one element matches. which doesn't seem to be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

you should test each string in your array not put your whole array in regex.test

```
var titleIs = ['Knit', 'Main'];
var words = ['Woven', 'Main'];
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + words.join('|') + ')$');
for(var i=0;i<titleIs.length;i++)
if (regex.test(titleIs[i])) {
alert("true")
break;
}
```

Comment: This alerts several times if more than one element matches. which doesn't seem to be desirable.

Comment: ok then when the first element matches break the loop, i edited the answer

Comment: good, now it works, however I think refactoring is always a good idea. (see my answer). in fact if you had written a separate method in the first place, this bug had never happened :)