# title attribute array

Tags: javascript, variables, attributes

Hi I'm getting the title attribute "Knit, Main". At the moment the var thinks that it is one word is there some symbol like "," that will make the var handle them in an array?

title="Knit, Main"

```
var titleIs = [this.title];
alert(titleIs.length); // at the moment this is 1
```

Comment: Something like [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var titles = this.title.split(/,\s?/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript `split` function

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Surely you meant to link http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14 or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
var titleIs = this.title; //if use this.title like string not array [this.title]
alert(titleIs.split(/,\s?/));
```

Comment: It will raise an error, since JavaScript arrays don't have native `split` method.

Comment: Just read my comment again thoroughly, or simply try to run your snippet. And don't refer to W3Schools, it is [bad resource](http://w3fools.org).

Comment: @VisioN you'r correct about array thank!!!... but please, keep your bad opinion about resources.